# I want to run the for loop between certain seconds

Tags: javascript, time, click

I want to click multiple buttons with a loop between certain seconds, but the loop waits for the second I specified at first, then clicks all the buttons without waiting for the time.

How can I get it to click at the specified intervals I want?

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".x .y");
var length = selector.length;

function click(){

    for (var i = 0, len = length; i < len; i++) {
        selector[i].click();
    };    

};

setInterval(click, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This waits 5 seconds, then clicks buttons with 1 second in between

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".x .y");
var length = selector.length;

function click(){

    for (var i = 0, len = length; i < len; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => selector[i].click(), i * 1000);
    };    

};

setInterval(click, 5000);
```